As matters stand - meaning
What does the phrase 'as matters stand' mean in the following sentences?

As the matter stands, the team needs to practice for two more weeks before the tournament.

"The answer is the president (Cyril Ramaphosa) will indicate what the final position of South Africa is. As matters stand an invitation has been issued to all (BRICS) heads of state," she said. – the Japan Times.

But as matters stand, the tightrope is wobbling wildly and the spectres of the abyss - an Israeli land invasion of Gaza, a wider war drawing in Hezbollah, Lebanon and Syria, or a direct Israeli confrontation with Iran - beckon dangerously.-The Guardian

As matters stand, the profession may never recover from the defamatory portrait of clinical hypnosis that is enshrined in Elizabeth Lamb.
-The New Yorker

Three additional forms of weapon systems, most of them American, are vital: heavy armour, long-range missiles and air defence. First, heavy armoured vehicles, especially tanks. As matters stand, the Ukrainian armed forces remain largely equipped with Russian or ex-Soviet equipment.



The phrase as matters stand can be used when we're discussing a particular situation or circumstance.  This site gives several synonyms including "at present", "currently", "in the current climate", "under existing conditions", "based on current circumstances", and "as it stands now".
All of these can fit into the OP's examples.
